# Open in Terminal context menu only opens terminal in home directory

Tags: unity, command-line, nautilus

Been testing out Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop. I noticed that right click menu (when right clicked on desktop or in the file manager) has open in terminal. But when I choose, not matter what directory I am in, the terminal open in my root home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package nautilus-open-terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

The bad news is that you will have two options now in your right-click menu. The good news is that one of them works.

Comment: No way to remove the non-working option?

Comment: @Sir_FZ yes, you can remove (be sure to back up) the following file: `/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libterminal-nautilus.so`. I did not recommend it because Im not sure how safe it is to manually remove the file. After removing though, you might need to restart.